# Intermittently working hardware/software breakpoints with STM32H7

Tags: stm32, embedded, debugging, stm32cubeide, stm32h

Problem: I have experienced issues with hardware/software breakpoints not being hit during debugging sessions in STM32CubeIDE with the STM32H743. When breakpoints are set or disabled during a debugging session, I often need to terminate and relaunch debugging several times or start a new debugging session for all set breakpoints to be hit. I have also had mixed results with the "Skip all breakpoints" functionality.

Details: The projects I am working on are C and C++ projects and both compilers are set to the same optimization settings. I have experienced this issue with both the debug compiler settings set to no optimizations or optimized for debugging. The debugger used is the SEGGER J-LINK.

Question: What steps can be taken to ensure breakpoints function properly during debugging sessions?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @VoltageSpike the OP writes that they're using STM32CubeIDE.

Comment: I am not sure about STM32CubeIDE, but generaly this kind of issue is caused by wrongly handled edge cases in development tools ignoring underlaying errors. In many ARM MCU IDE this behaviour happes just when you try insert more hardware breakpoints that CPU actually supports. Segger J-Link generaly cheks on this, but are errors from J-Link in STM32CubeIDE handled correctly? Try add 10 breakpoints and see whats happens. But of cousrese it may be caused by different error.

Comment: Is it a real genuine Segger JLink, or a clone. If you don't know, did it cost a few dollars or a few hundred dollars?

Comment: @Misaz Adding 10 breakpoints worked during a recent debugging session. I will keep an eye out for behavior when I get a message about going over the hardware breakpoint number.

Comment: @Justme It cost several hundreds of dollars and should be genuine.

Comment: 10 breakpoints should not work. If it work, your debug environment most probybly use Segger unlimited flash breakpoints or something like this. This ususlay work but most probably can cause issues which you mention.

Comment: Great, then you can ask Segger for support for using their product. Or ST for support on using their product with genuine Segger. There might be an update for the debugger firmware, PC drivers, and gdb server, and the debugger program itself. On the other hand, if the problem is not on debugging side, it could be in STM32 hardware or software, and for that we need schematics and code. Maybe signal integrity issue on debug pins?

Comment: Please note that some debugger IDEs struggle with placing breakpoints in optimized C code. Eclipse in particular is infamous. A solution to that might be to either disable all optimization in the debug build, or to set the breakpoints not on the C level but on the assembler level - any half decent debugger will support breakpoints and single stepping on the assembler level.